# Dealing with failed records in an Upsert operation

Tags: data-loader, upsert, externalid, jitterbit, accountcontactrelation

With the help of responses to my previous posts I was finally successful in Upserting Contacts in Salesforce via Jitterbit using External Id. However two records failed. I am thinking these failed because there are two entries with same value in Ext_Contact_ID.

I have **enabled Contact to Multiple Accounts**.

The Upsert operation is on Contact. I tested with a small data set of 7 records.

[image]
**Output**

5 successful records

2 failed records

[image]

**Question**:

- Do I need a 2nd query on AccountContactRelationship object to be able
  to upsert Contact's that are associated to multiple Accounts?   If
  so, how can i UPSERT into AccountCOntactRelationShip using an
  external Id?
  (Per SF Documentation for AccountContactRelationship we
  need AccountId, ContactId, RecordOwner. )

Comment: Is that real PII (personally identifiable information) in your screenshot?

Comment: I've removed the two screenshots because they appeared to contain actual persons' information. If that's not the case, you're welcome to edit them back in, or show us examples with fake data.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed for being diligent.  That's fake made up data.

Comment: Thank you for confirming! I've rolled your question back to your original version.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed